# RxJava, show updated list in Activity's onResume

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I need to fill the RecylcerView with list of data when activity starts. I implemented this by subscribe, where in onSuccess method I showing my list.
But how can I again show updated list when Activity onResume. I mean after switching to another activity and then on returned to previous, I need to show updated RecylcerView again. How can I implemented this, or I need every time subscribe for showing. Maybe multiple subscribe on same observable in Activity's onResume is a bad practice?

Presenter

```
@Override
public void setCitiesList() {
    disposables.add(getCitiesListObservable()
            .subscribe(list -> view.showCitiesList(list)));

}

private Single<List<City>> getCitiesListObservable() {
    Observable<City> citiesFromDb = dataManager.getCitiesFromDb();
    return citiesFromDb
           .switchMapSingle(city ->
            // logic
}
```

Activity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    presenter.setCitiesList();
}
```

In a word, how can I avoid multiple subscribing? I need to show updated cities on each onResume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Observable subscribe() method returns a Disposable object that you are adding to disposables. Calling the Disposable dispose() method and removing the Subscription from your disposables should solve this.

Because you are targeting a specific disposable in your onResume, it would likely be cleaner to store the disposable as an independent instance variable.

```
Disposable cityListDisposable;

@Override
public void setCitiesList() {
    cityListDisposable = getCitiesListObservable()
            .subscribe(list -> view.showCitiesList(list));

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (cityListDisposable != null) {
        cityListDisposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand your thought. As I need to call setCitiesList() method everytime in onResume, so to avoid multiple subscribing, I need to call onPause method of Presenter (if(city.....,), whic u wrote), and this method calling in Activity's onPause. But as a can see we don't add this cityListDisposable  to disposables (in my situation disposalbes is instance of CompositeDisposable, "global array of all disposables". All my disposables contains in CompositeDisposables (disposables), expect cityListcityListDisposable,right?

Comment: If you have more than one disposable in the activity, then using a CompositeDisposable makes sense. in which case add disposables.add(cityListDisposable) in the second line of setCitiesList(). Then calling disposables.dispose(cityListDisposable) would accomplish the same result.

Comment: So, I have 2 ideas. 
1) as u wrote, dispose cityListDisposable in onPause, and don't adding it to global disposables (CompositeDisposable)
2) add cityListDisposable to disposables and clear() disposables not onlt in onDestroy but on onPause too

Comment: Yep, I have not only cityListDisposable in this Activity, I have more too, so that approach 1-st or 2-nd would be better

Comment: Sorry, I'm newer in RxJava. As I understood from your 2nd comment, the best variant is to use CompositeDisposables but in onPause call disposables.dispose(cityListDisposable). Thus I won't be subscribe on every onResume and this approach allows to prevent adding same observable to disposables

Comment: I made a mistake with my initial comment. Calling disposables.remove(cityListDisposable)  **NOT dispose** in your onPause should solve your problem. Because it is the only Disposable that is being initialized in your onResume, it should be the only Disposable that you dispose in onPause(). That way you can leave disposables.clear() in the onDestroy.

Comment: I understood, thanks. In onDestroy I will use disposables.clear(), but onPause I will dispose only this cityListDisposable using disposables.remove(cityListDisposable). Thank u bro!)